# Can you cure fish in jar?

Tags: fish, pickling, curing

Since it will be cold for some time, I was thinking of using my detached, unheated shed to pickle some veggies.  But another thought I was having was to actually cure/can some herrings or sardines (or another kind of blue fish) in a jar with water and salt.

Is it possible to do that similar to how veggies are pickled?  I was thinking that the brine I would put the fish in would act as a preservative and the fish would be edible after some time of curing?  Is this doable or is it just a bats**t crazy idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had some success with this recipe: http://awesomepickle.com/pickled-herring-recipe-how-to-fillet-a-fish/

The fish should keep for a couple of weeks once pickled, but I always tend to eat mine in the first few days.